# Paris with a less touristic neighborhood

Tags: france, paris

I know that's Paris is a touristic city, anyway, I guess that's probably a *arrondissement* or area with less touristic moviment. So, I'm looking for a non-tourist neighborhood to stay for a few days and eat like a local. Then, my question is:

**What is the best neighborhood to stay as a local (non-turist neighborhood)?**

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `eating like a local`? Paris is a touristy city yes, but you will find that the monuments are intertwined in the urban pattern hence everywhere you go you'll find both locals and tourists. That's actually the beauty of Paris.

Comment: @JoErNanO Like I said, I know that Paris is a mix of cultures and countries. Anyway, it probably have a neighborhood less touristic. I'm looking for a zone/area where will have more locals living than tourist hotels in everywhere.

Comment: Importantly... Do you want to stay *inside* the Peripherique or outside?  Or alternatively outside the Peripherique but inside of the A86?  It makes a big difference.

Comment: Voting to close this as opinion-based. IMHO anyone can say they live in the true autochthonous Paris but it becomes kinda hard to prove.

Comment: Me too. It's very opinion-based and Paris is BIG. I like to stay south of the 'Mouf', but the most NON-touristy locale would definitely include La Defence.  But so boring.......

Comment: I tend to like to discover places that are not so touristy, but mostly after I visited touristy areas. As the others said above, this is usually boring, touristy places are usually the places with more appeal. And Paris still has over 2 million people living there (so, not tourists). In practice, just walk 10 minutes away from any touristy place and you will be living like any Parisian.

Comment: 'eat like a local' would include Maghrebian cuisine since arabs and berbers make up such a large portion of the local population :)

Answer (score 0):

[The Père-Lachaise/Gambetta Neighborhood in Paris](http://goparis.about.com/od/parisneighborhoods/a/Gambetta-Menilmontant-neighborhood-paris.htm)

> For a taste of how real Parisians live, head over to the Père Lachaise/Gambetta neighborhood ...  you’ll find quirky, family-owned cafes and bars

In a forum thread on [Fodor's](http://www.fodors.com/community/europe/neighborhood-of-pere-lachaise-whats-it-like.cfm) you will find statements like:

> I live in this area ... for "safety and Parisian character", Gambetta can hardly be beat!